# Unknown length of chromosone in genetic algorithm

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithms

I've read some about genetic algorithms and the general approach, but I haven't found anything about using it when the length of the solution is unknown. How would the generation of the initial population look like? Would mutation then include adding/removing alleless? Are there any general methods for this?

Comment: In general, the answers are all yes.  But you haven't provided much information to work with here.  You want definitely to able to "hit" all possible genes, so sometimes adding must be necessary.  Often you can choose to encode the genes as fix length, e.g. in travelling salesman or subset problems.

Comment: @PålGD So is there any general approach or should I just think logically? In my case there is a game where you have to find a solution in a finite number of moves, but it could be 1 move or much more.

Comment: Does every gene have a well-defined fitness?  You have to balance between generating any possible gene, or only feasible genes.

Comment: I don't think there are any general approaches, you will have to try different strategies to see what works.  You can _relax_ the problem/game by removing rules and see which mutations/crossovers gives you best fitness.

Comment: Depending also on your score landscape, there are frameworks that take into account covariance and expected improvements, but I'm not sure that would be possible in your situation.

Comment: One last comment;  I got some insight by tracing each individual's heritage (how it was created, e.g. `RMCMMCMMMMCMM`could mean that it consisted mainly of mutations), and also how much its fitness improved in each generation.

Comment: @PålGD Thanks for the info. I can easily calculate a fitness by evaluating the score of the game with the moves. From what I've read one approach is to generate each possible gene and then when a move isn't feasible give it, during evaluation, a bad fitness, so that's my initial idea at least.

Comment: I would try as hard as possible to _only create feasible genes_ ... If you allow for any mutation and crossover, they may waste a lot of computation time, but this is again a trade-off.

Comment: @PålGD Yes, I understand your reasoning, I believe it's very hard in my specific case though.

Comment: @PålGD Hey, I have another question. In this case the chromosome is representing moves, sometimes a move isn't available and thus I found two options, penalize the solution OR ignore the move and take the next if there is any. The second gives a much better result but requires a modification (to remove all moves that was ignored) after a solution has been found. Is the second option valid according to GA though?

Comment: Yes, everything is allowed.  It's not surprising that it works better.  A "crossover algorithm" can be _take the first $k$ moves from A and then fill the remaining with legal moves from B_ .    That way, you keep the order of the moves intact, you create only "feasible" chromosomes, and you don't lose as much time by creating "extremely bad" (illegal) chromosomes.

Comment: @PålGD Okay, thanks. The problem is that I don't know before the evaluation what moves are illegal or not, thus I either have to modify the chromosome after each evaluation to get only legal moves or wait for the final solution and only modify that one.

Comment: Okay, yes, that can of course also happen.  You must then choose to penalize with infinite, *or* if you can assess how far away from a valid chromosome you are, you can penalize accordingly.  You can of course add heuristics to skew the probability of generating valid chromosomes, as in, adhere to the easiest-to-verify rules.

Comment: @PålGD Ye, penalize was one approach but as I mentioned above I could just "ignore" that move and move on to the next one in the vector. Thus I could get valid solution anyway and then afterwards remove all illegal moves.